# How to list by only Amazon product?

Tags: amazon

Is it possible to list item sorting by only ones sold by Amazon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for what you need. Once on the listings on the right hand side you will see 'sellers'  [image: le this]

Just hit +See more to see all the sellers. Amazon.com should be an option. If not, they don't sell it